# Excluding files from Sonarqube

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying not to analyse test files with Sonarqube.

I have several Maven subprojects and the test files are under these paths:

`subproject1/src/test/`, `subproject2/src/test/` and so on

I'm passing the following option from Maven:

`-Dsonar.exclusion=src/test/**`

However, the test files are still analysed.

I also tried:

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/src/test/**,**/test/*,subproject1/src/test/**,**/*Spec.scala
```

But issues are still raised on test code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add details on the kind of evidence of analysis you are seeing.

Comment: What do you mean? I see that Sonarqube is building the code, and then under `Issues`, I see that there are issues found in the test folders as well.

Comment: So what information do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property by the name `sonar.exclusion`. `sonar.exclusions` **is** a valid property, but it applies to *source* files. You're trying to exclude *test* files - and yes the scanners *do* make the distinction, especially for Maven projects.

You should use instead `sonar.test.exclusions`

If you want to omit only certain rules, you have two options:

- remove the rule from your profile
- use **Administration > Analysis Scope > Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria** to turn the rule off for only a subset of files.

Comment: What if I want to disable only a specific rule,  like for instance having 25% of code as comments?  Is it something like `sonar.test.exclusions.rule`? Is there a list with the names of these rules somewhere?

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way of doing this from Maven?

Comment: You can set properties in your pom file, but I'd recommend using the UI instead.

Comment: So how can I set the properties in the POM file? Is there any guide? I can't use the UI because I have a different build for every Git pull request(and there are many)

Comment: At this point we're getting into "discussion" territory and should probably move elsewhere [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) but if all your builds point to the same SonarQube project, there's no reason not to set this via the UI

Comment: Ok, but is there any documentation about adding these options to Maven? Do you have a link?